# Can a circular ring posses moment of area?

Tags: moment

My civil lab exam constituted of 10 multiple choice questions. One of the question asked was if the "moment of area" of a solid circular plate was less than that of a circular ring of the  same diameter. My teacher says that the statement is true but I assume that the statement is false.

The facts that make me think so is :

1- If the area we take into consideration is the total area covered by the solid or the whole of the ring, then their moment of areas have to be the same for both.

2- If the area we take into consideration is the area covered by the particles that make up the body, of course, then the area considered will be very much less for ring than for circular solid.

So, either way it contradicts the statement.

3- Nowhere could I find "moment of area" for a circular ring.

So, am I correct here?

Comment: When you speak of a ring, Is it a 1D ring? 2D?3D?

Comment: Have you asked your teacher to explain his/her reasons?

Comment: @Mauricio It's a 2D ring

Comment: @sammygerbil She seems to use the concept of moment of inertia

Comment: What does she say about your reasoning? Does she agree you are correct? If not, what does she say is wrong with your reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question asked about a disk and ring of equal areas, then the teacher would be correct. This case would be roughly equivalent to comparing the moment of inertia of a solid wheel and ring wheel of the same diameter and mass.

However, if the question indeed is about the same diameter, then the MoA of the disk equals the MoA of the ring plus the MoA of the portion of the disk inside the ring. Because the latter is positive, the MoA of the disk is larger than that of the ring.

I assumed the ring is not infinitely thin, for which the MoA would be zero.